# Banking platform accepts password containing subset of real password

Tags: passwords, banks

How would it be possible that if my password was `123abc` that my bank also accepts something like `123abc12`?

Isn't that an extreme security flaw? If the password was hashed and salted, wouldn't the latter create a completely different digest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not mean that your bank is storing your passwords in a plaintext format. The bank could simply be truncating the input password to a certain length before hashing it.

It *is* a security flaw as there is no good reason to artificially limit the length of passwords, but it might not be as bad storing passwords in plaintext. I would write to them and demand an explanation of why they are doing this.

Comment: Yeah you are right. My password is exactly 16 characters long, everything entered after that would be truncated I guess.

Comment: Financial systems often have mainframes in the backend, and mainframes often have password length limitations which chain outward to customer-facing systems.